# __init__ and instance show different values for instance attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I am attempting to create a subclass of `Response` from the "Requests" library for Python. When I execute the following with Python 2.7.6 and Requests 2.5.3:

```py
import requests

class Page(requests.Response):
    # A Page is a Response that reported itself to be OK (HTTP "200").

    def __init__(self, url):
        requests.Response.__init__(self)
        self = requests.get(url)
        assert self.status_code is 200
        print "Status code according to __init__: " + str(self.status_code)

p = Page("http://www.google.com/")
print "Status code according to instance: " + str(p.status_code)
```

I get this output:

```
Status code according to __init__: 200
Status code according to instance: None
```

This is surprising to me. I thought those two calls were addressing the same attribute of the same instance, and had therefore expected them to give the same output.

Indeed, all of the instance's attributes show themselves to be populated when called from `__init__` (i.e. not just `self.status_code` but also `self.text`, etc). Yet, if I call the same attributes from the instance (e.g. `p.text`), they yield `None` or suchlike, as though they had not been initialized.

Why this disparity between what `__init__` sees and what the instance sees?

Comment: You're redefining `self`. Never a good idea.

Comment: @BryanOakley, agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Evidently those two calls were **not** addressing the same attribute of the same instance. That is why they did not give the same output. This solves the problem, by creating a Request object and then copying its attributes to the Page object:

```
import requests

class Page(requests.Response):
    # A Page is a Response that has been retrieved and found OK (HTTP "200").

    def __init__(self, url):
        requests.Response.__init__(self)
        r = requests.get(url)
        self.__dict__.update(r.__dict__)
        assert self.status_code is 200
        print "Status code according to __init__: " + str(self.status_code)

p = Page("http://www.google.com/")
print "Status code according to object: " + str(p.status_code)
```

I suspect there's a more elegant solution available (although I haven't come up with one yet), so I'll not mark this question as "answered" for now. Please submit a better solution if you have one!